# Hyperledger composer

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

I'm new to hyperledger composer and linux environment, will hyperledger composer run on ubuntu 20.04LTS?The prerequisite says it should be ubuntu 16.04 but I've seen it working on ubuntu 18.04 .

Answer (score 0):

From 29th August 2019, the Hyperledger Composer project is in deprecated. None of the maintainers are actively developing new features. You should avoid the use of hyperledger composer.